# Find readable with Permissions as POSIX?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

Aimed systems: Linux and OS X. Original [code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287063/16920) which works in Ubuntu 16.04 but not OS X, but follows unsuccessfully [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) standards

```
gfind ~ ! -readable -prune -o -type f -name "*.tex"
```

where

- `!` is about *Negation of a primary; the unary NOT operator.*
- `-readable` TODO this does not seem to be POSIX
- `-prune` is about *The primary shall always evaluate as true; it shall cause find not to descend the current pathname if it is a directory. If the -depth primary is specified, the -prune primary shall have no effect.*
- `-o` is about *Alternation of primaries; the OR operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is true.* That is if not, then this.
- `-type` about type, here file `f`
- `-name` about filename, here `*.tex`

Output

```
gfind: paths must precede expression: type
Usage: gfind [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

### Fix proposal

Use `-perm 0744` instead of `-readable` but not sure if it is equivalent

```
gfind ~ ! -perm 0744 -prune -o -type f -name "*.tex"
```

Output: `/Users/masi`. Expected output: list of .tex files.

---

How can you set permissions of find correctly for readable?

Comment: Well where did you get find from and what version as it is **not** part of OSX (in general from your other posts Linux is not Unix they differ if you want non standard things stick to Linux :) If you want the same in general don't use GNU extensions

Comment: As I said don't use GNU extensions - some things will differ but BSD is normally a subset - i.e. don't assume that Linux is the correct way,

Comment: If you truly want to write portable scripts then I suggest you start here- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/contents.html to learn the POSIX standards for the shell and its utilities. Most scripts that I write in OS X will run in Linux.

Comment: I'm going to let you do the work. Add the `-user` option (It can be a variable) then check whether the `-perm` is readable.

Comment: @fd0 Can you throw some light about `-user`, see patrix comment in his answer.

Comment: In patrix `find . -perm +0666` example, it is possible to list a file where the owner is not the caller but only that owner can read the file. `-perm` reads permission bit without regards to the file's classifications. So, building `find` 's logic may involve using the `-user` and `-group`options along with `-perm` options. Of course this can be overly complex and hard to debug. I'll post a solution when I have time to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double negation at the beginning makes this rather complex. Just using

```
gfind . -readable -type f -name '*.tex'
```

should work.

PS: Or `find . -perm +0666 -type f -name '*.tex'` for the default `find`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the double negation! I have had it all the time in mind but could not find a way to solve it.

Comment: Do you know what fd0 means about `-user` option here in his comment? I am still thinking about it but I cannot understand.

Comment: Don't see how `-user` (which checks for ownership, not readability) would help here. But maybe @fd0 can throw some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to use `find`'s options `-user`,`-group`, and `-perm`, the `find` command quickly became unmanageable. An inline script with `find` using the shell's `-r test` would be portable between the two operating systems.

```
find ~ -type f -name '*.tex' -exec sh -c 'for file
do
    [ -r "$file" ] && echo "$file"
done
' sh {} + 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: You are throwing away something to `/dev/null`. Why?

Comment: @Masi Well, you should know why. You have asked similar questions before- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find .

Comment: I asked it because I do not like to throw away such things. It is much better to handle the things, and prevent such things in the first place.